# Forward everything over SSL in an Express.js App

Tags: ssl, curl, https, dns, redirect

Can't seem to get all of these to forward through SSL. Ideally, this would be done without a Wildcard Certificate.

http://baredomain.com
https://baredomain.com
http://www.baredomain.com
https://www.baredomain.com

Ideally all of the above if typed into the browser or curled will send all traffic over https://www.baredomain.com or https://baredomain.com (just one, not both).

I've tried a combo of A-records, CNAME records and node.js redirecting code. I can't seem to get this working. I've tried lots of different configurations and gotten close at best.

I'm trying to get to an ideal setup for node.js apps. I've been working on many and in order for people to be able to get to them without trouble all the routes listed above need to work.

**Update**: Hmm... seems there's something called a SAN (Subject Alternative Name) as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could also have two individual certs for each of the names.  If your goal is lower cost, a SAN cert for baredomain.com with www.baredomain.com as a SAN dnsname would work fine.

That plus some simple redirect code like

```
app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
  if (/^www\./.test(req.headers.host)) {
    res.redirect(301, 'http://'+req.headers.host.replace(/^www\./,'')+req.url);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

should do it.

Comment: Sounds cool, what would the redirect be for? Just to strip out the www?

Comment: Yup, that'll standardize anything www.* to just the base domain.  Could do it the reverse way, forcing the base domain to the www.* form: `if (!/www\./.test(req.headers.host)) { res.redirect(301, 'http://www.'+req.headers.host+req.url); } ...`

Comment: Awesome, sounds like a great solution. Would probably be okay, but for whatever reason my current host is having trouble dealing with the bare domain. I have a wild card cert with the bare domain as a SAN (Subject Alternative Name).